Jest test to show toast notification is not working
I am trying to write a jest test for a scenario where the apex wire service fails and triggers a toast notification . However the expect statement returns false. What could be the issue?
html
<template>
    <lightning-card class="slds-is-relative">
       <!-- The template and lightning-spinner goes here -->
       <template lwc:if={isLoading}>
           <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium" variant="brand"></lightning-spinner>
       </template>
       <!-- The lightning-map goes here -->
       <template lwc:else>
            <lightning-map
                map-markers={mapMarkers}>
            </lightning-map>
       </template>
       <div slot="footer">Top 10 Only!</div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

js
// imports
import { LightningElement, wire,api } from 'lwc';
import getBoatsByLocation from '@salesforce/apex/BoatDataService.getBoatsByLocation';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
const LABEL_YOU_ARE_HERE = 'You are here!';
const ICON_STANDARD_USER = 'standard:user';
const ERROR_TITLE = 'Error loading Boats Near Me';
const ERROR_VARIANT = 'error';
export default class BoatsNearMe extends LightningElement {
  @api boatTypeId = '';
  mapMarkers = [];
  isLoading = true;
  isRendered;
  latitude;
  longitude;
  
  // Add the wired method from the Apex Class
  // Name it getBoatsByLocation, and use latitude, longitude and boatTypeId
  // Handle the result and calls createMapMarkers
  @wire (getBoatsByLocation, {latitude: '$latitude',longitude: '$longitude',boatTypeId: '$boatTypeId'})
  wiredBoatsJSON({error, data}) {
        console.log('In wire...');
        console.log(this.isLoading);
        if(data){
            console.log(data);
            this.createMapMarkers(JSON.parse(data));
            console.log('Processed data');
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
        if(error){
            console.log('Error...');
            this.mapMarkers = undefined;
            const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: ERROR_TITLE,
                message: error.message,
                variant: ERROR_VARIANT
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
            console.log('Toast dispatched...');
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
   }
  
  // Controls the isRendered property
  // Calls getLocationFromBrowser()
  renderedCallback() {
      console.log('In render callback');
      console.log(this.isLoading);
      if (!this.isRendered) {
          this.getLocationFromBrowser();
      }
      this.isRendered = true;
      //this.isLoading = true;
  }
  
  // Gets the location from the Browser
  // position => {latitude and longitude}
  getLocationFromBrowser() {
    //const myLocationService = getLocationService();
    //if (myLocationService.isAvailable()) {
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
          console.log(this.latitude);
          console.log(this.longitude);
      },error => {
        console.log(error.message);
        const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: ERROR_TITLE,
            message: error.message,
            variant: ERROR_VARIANT
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
      });
    }
}
  
  // Creates the map markers
  createMapMarkers(boatData) {
    const newMarkers = boatData.map(boat => {
        //console.log(boat.Name);
        return {
            title: boat.Name,
            location: {
                Latitude: boat.Geolocation__Latitude__s,
                Longitude: boat.Geolocation__Longitude__s
            }
        };
    });
    newMarkers.unshift({
          title: LABEL_YOU_ARE_HERE,
          icon: ICON_STANDARD_USER,
          location: {
              Latitude: this.latitude,
              Longitude: this.longitude
          }
    });
    this.mapMarkers = newMarkers;
   }
}```

Jest test:
```import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import BoatsNearMe from 'c/boatsNearMe';
import getBoatsByLocation from '@salesforce/apex/BoatDataService.getBoatsByLocation';
import { ShowToastEventName } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
const mockboatLocationRecords = require('./data/getBoatsByLocation.json');
jest.mock(
    '@salesforce/apex/BoatDataService.getBoatsByLocation',() => {
        const { createApexTestWireAdapter } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest');
        return {
            default: createApexTestWireAdapter(jest.fn()),
        }
    },
    {virtual:true}
);


describe('c-boats-near-me', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });
    const mockGeolocation = {
        getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
            .mockImplementation((success) => Promise.resolve(success({
                coords: {
                    latitude: 10,
                    longitude: 10
                }
            })))
    };
    navigator.geolocation = mockGeolocation;

    it('Test error', () => {
        // Arrange
        const element = createElement('c-boats-near-me', {
            is: BoatsNearMe
        });

        // Act
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        const handler = jest.fn();
        // Add event listener to catch toast event
        element.addEventListener(ShowToastEventName, handler);
        getBoatsByLocation.error();

        // Assert
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
           expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});

